# Wordpress permalink change category

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

Currently my web address reads:

`http://www.mydomain.com/services-view/athelte/`

I want it to read:

`http://www.mydomain.com/the-team/athelte/`

Replacing `/services-view` with `/the-team`

the client used the "services" as their team lineup, and wants the web address to change respectively.
I know it's not in permalinks, where would i find changing the title/category of services to the-team.

Comment: So whats `services-view` is? Page, Post or Category?

Comment: You should be able to go into your Admin > Posts > Categories, click "Quick Edit" on the category in question, and then change the slug (basically the URL portion of such category). Not sure if this would create an automatic redirect, however.

Comment: @Rahil my guess: category as question suggest. At 3Cdesign: try change of category slug from services-view to the-team

Comment: its neither a post or a category, it's a like "plugin" if you will but its not something you can install like a plugin, the best way to describe it is, if you bought a wordpress theme, they would have like portfolio, services, testimonials, on their left menu bar.  this one happens to say services, and they used the services as their athletes.  do i have to go into the functions file? or?

Comment: You have to look in the theme functions or you can download your theme folder and with a SublimeText or some text editor search `services-view` to see where is placed.